# Displayproblems with checkboxes/radiobuttons in differen browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a web application using bootstrap. It has to run in different Browsers.

I have multiple groups with Headlines and checkboxes, which are looking like this:

```
<div>
     <h4>Liniensicherungen</h4>
     <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="cbxGrundliniensicherung" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Mit Grundliniensicherung:</label>
               <div class="col-sm-6 paddingRadioBtn">
                    <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="cb_mit_grund_liniensicherung_runs_show" id="cbxGrundliniensicherung">
          </div>
     <div>
<div>
```

It is working in Firefox and IE but in Chrome the checkboxes (and radiobuttons) are looking different. They are bigger and have a small grey border above.

as below it looks in Firefox.
[image: This]

And as below is how it looks in Chrome.
[image: this]

Does anyone know, how to change the look in Chrome?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: provide css of this so we can solve it

Comment: For this part i dont have additional css classes (the class paddingRadioBtn just adds padding-top: 5px). Im  using the default bootstrap classes form-group and col-sm-6.

Comment: i investigated the elements with the browser inspector but couldnt find anything that explains this behavior.

Comment: look my answer and if you have problem tell me

Comment: if you want you can override their css

Comment: form-control usually used for text-area

Answer (score 0):

First of all in checkbox you don't want to add `form-control`, that class creates big checkbox so, remove it

for checkbox there is default class called `form-check-input` and for real position you need to add `form-check` in parent class but if you dont want to add this stuff there is OK !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"> 
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> -->
 <style></style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
     <h4>Liniensicherungen</h4>
     <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="cbxGrundliniensicherung" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Mit Grundliniensicherung:</label>
               <div class="col-sm-6 paddingRadioBtn form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="cb_mit_grund_liniensicherung_runs_show" id="cbxGrundliniensicherung">
          </div>
     <div>
<div>

<!-- Scripts are here -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> -->
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

usually the form-control is used for text area but if you want to use it you can override the css or you can use the custom input checkbox

```css
.form-control{width:20px!important;
font-size:5px!important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
     <h4>Liniensicherungen</h4>
     <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="cbxGrundliniensicherung" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Mit Grundliniensicherung:</label>
               <div class="col-sm-6 paddingRadioBtn">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control"aria-label="Text input with checkbox"  name="cb_mit_grund_liniensicherung_runs_show" id="cbxGrundliniensicherung">
          </div>
     <div>
<div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```